# Gradle configure sub project plugin

Tags: docker, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Hello I'm new on gradle.
Here is the structure of my project

```
rootProject
├── build.gradle.kts
├── subproject1
│   ├── build.gradle.kts
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── src...
├── subproject2
│   ├── build.gradle.kts
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── src...
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── README.md
├── README.pdf
└── settings.gradle.kts
```

I want to share some configuration of a plugin between subprojects without apply plugin to root projet. How I can do that ?

build.gradle.kts of root project.

```kotlin
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.docker).apply(false)
}

subprojects{
    apply(plugin = "com.palantir.docker")

    docker{
        //configure subproject docker plugin
    }
}
```

thanks for help ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `apply(...)` is legacy and shouldn't be used, you should always use `plugins { ... }` to apply plugins.

For Kotlin DSL build scripts, you only get type-safe accessors like `docker { ... }` if you used the non-legacy way to apply plugins, that is using `plugins { ... }`.

If you use the legacy way to apply a plugin like you did, you need to configure the extension by type like `configure<DockerExtensionOrWhateverItsTypeIs> { ... }` instead of `docker { ... }`.

That you do not want to apply the plugin to the root project just to configure it for the subprojects is good. And it shows you one of the many reasons it is a bad idea to use `subprojects { ... }` or `allprojects { ... }`. This cross-project configuration is highly discouraged nowadays and works against more sophisticated Gradle features. Instead, you should use convention plugins, implemented for example as precompiled script plugins in `buildSrc` or an included build to share build logic between multiple projects.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
This brings me to another question: is the following a good practice?

```kotlin
subprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    version = "xxx"
    group = "xxx"
    apply(plugin = "java") // Surely this isn't?
    tasks.withType<Jar> { // Not this either?
        archiveVersion.set("")
    }
    tasks.withType<JavaCompile> {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17.toString()
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17.toString()
    }
}

Comment: Of course not as I just told you. `subprojects { ... }` is bad. `apply(...)` is bad. `...Compatibility` can be set, but I'd use JVM toolchains instead.